# Renting a motorcycle in Bangkok for one day up to 500 Baht in first quarter of 2020

Tags: thailand, rental, bangkok, motorcycles

I need to rent a motorcycle (a simple automatic scooter, the simplest you can think of), in Bangkok for no more than 500 Baht, in first quarter of 2020.

I think about this and it feels to me unlikely to be possible,

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web search for **Bangkok motorscooter hire** finds quite a few results, and indeed you can ret for as little as 250 (presumably Baht) per day.